# Which interface is an immediate predecessor to Iterator interface in Java?

Tags: java, interface, iterator

I'm looking for an interface that was replaced by *Iterator*, which has been here since Java 1.2, apparently. I'm using this predecessor interface in an assignment, and I can't seem to find any actual leads. I can't find anything concrete on my end, so I was hoping for someone here to help me out.

*BinarySearchTree*, *AbstractGraph*, and *DelegatingGraph* are what I found when looking for *Iterator*'s predecessor, and they all have methods that implement *Iterator*, thus rendering them useless to me in this case.

Thank you for reading this post.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps you're referring to Enumeration? The [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Enumeration.html) says:

*"The functionality of this interface is duplicated by the Iterator interface. In addition, Iterator adds an optional remove operation, and has shorter method names. New implementations should consider using Iterator in preference to Enumeration."*

Comment: I think you're right: the Enumeration even came out in Java 1.0, as opposed to the other "interfaces" I looked at, which turned out to be classes. I'll be using this for now unless my instructor says different.